# How can I create an executable file from this source code?

Tags: github

I'm using the `PKMN-NTR.exe` from this GitHub page (ver: 3.6-beta3): https://github.com/drgoku282/PKMN-NTR/releases

The program had a bug so I downloaded the "Source code (zip)" file and figured out how to fix it.

However I can't figure out how to create the `PKMN-NTR.exe` file from the source code.

Can someone instruct me on what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a C# project, and its wiki [has a page on compilation](https://github.com/drgoku282/PKMN-NTR/wiki/Compilation). Basically:

1. You need the source for PKMN-NTR as well as [this other project](https://github.com/kwsch/PKHeX.git)
2. Make sure you have these dependencies:

   - Costura.Fody
   - Octokit
   - .NET standard library
3. Then [build the project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/building-and-cleaning-projects-and-solutions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

If you're using Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 and the GitHub Extension it looks like all of the above is pretty straightforward. If you're not using Visual Studio you may have to adjust the instructions.

I suggest you read the entire wiki page.